# Proper way to convert two switch light/bath fan to single switch

Tags: wiring, switch, exhaust-fan

Currently have a 14/3 running from switches to bath fan - one hot for fan light and one hot for exhaust fan.

To put both light and fan on single switch, is it better to do it at the switch level or at the fixture level? ie should I tie and pigtail both hots to one switch inside the switch box only, or is it preferable to tie both light and fan to one hot in the fixture itself and then just cap off the other unused 14/3 hot at both ends.

One is easier to do, one requires crawling into the attic.

Edit: In response to the comments:

Regarding plan for second switch: I would remove the second switch and just have the one. To ensure exhaust is always on when the light is on in the kids’ bathroom.

Regarding if it’s a switch loop: It is not a switch loop - there is separate main hot coming into the switch box and the 14/3 goes from box to fan with the white neutral being true neutral

Regarding wiring access to fan from below: I think you are correct, I would need to remove the motor.

Comment: What are your plans for the second switch?  Is it a switch loop and the white wire is hot to the switches, and the black and red are switch hots?

Comment: You don't need to crawl into the attic to adjust your bath fan wiring. They're all accessible from below.

Comment: It appears that you've now created two accounts and that's why your edit to your own question went into the edit queue. Please follow the [instructions here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to get the accounts merged.

Answer (score 4):

Just take the load wires from the fan and light at the switch box, pigtail them together and connect the other end of the pigtail to the switch you want to keep. Remove the unused switch and cap the hot with a wire nut. You'll need a cover similar to [this one from Grainger](https://www.grainger.com/product/55KT94?gucid=N:N:PS:Paid:GGL:CSM-2295:4P7A1P:20501231&gclid=Cj0KCQjw0oyYBhDGARIsAMZEuMslukf3If-0q26bRH3qwNyitx3mfUxPi7X7fECPVONIOFZpvT1O5e8aApHhEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds).

[image]